# How to stop Google Chrome from thinking my flash is an Ad?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, video.js, autoplay, ads

So,

A few days ago, Google Chrome started to block Flash advertisement from auto-playing, **by default**.

The problem is that I'm using [videojs](http://videojs.com/) media player to play an HLS live stream on my page. 
And, since Chrome does not support HLS protocol natively, the player falls back to a small Flash file to play the video.

But Chrome thinks this Flash file is an AD - thus not allowing it to auto-play as it should.

Is there any way to tell Chrome that this file is actually an important part of my page, and not an AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty Flash file larger than 398x298 to the bottom of your page. I found once you have at least one Flash file above their minimum Chrome will not pause any of your Flash. You cannot hide this extra Flash file with CSS. Optionally use a javascript timeout (3 seconds) to hide the empty Flash file in case it messes with your page layout. I'm using swfObject for embedding.

Answer (score 1):

I am dealing with the same issue, but I think the size of the video and location on the page are factors. Try making the video player bigger. When I went up to 410x308 the problem went away.

Comment: Indeed! With some testing I found out that if (width < 398 or height < 298) then Chrome is blocking auto-play. I'll talk to our designers about fitting the player with these dimensions for now, but I'd still want a way to mark it as a "safe", or "non-ad" flash. Thanks for the tip!